# dlib serialization on custom object fails in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, serialization, dlib

I have a class defined in a namespace. I created the serialize/deserialize methods required by dlib to make it serializable, outside the namespace. It works well on Windows with VC++, but in Ubuntu with gcc doesn't, showing a compilation error saying the method cannot be found. When I remove the namespace from the class, the serialization works ok.

This is the first problem, because I don't know why it works in one compiler and not in the other, and I would prefer to leave the class with a namespace.

The other problem is that I need to serialize a class that cannot be without namespace, so I need to make it work with it.

Any idea is welcome, and if more information is required, I can provide it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to solve it. The problem was that I was declaring serialize/deserialize functions outside the namespace of the classes I wanted to serialize. I don't know why it works on VC++, but now it works in both compilers.